# gcloud functions deploy with gitlab Ci error

Tags: bash, google-cloud-functions, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am working in the deployment of `Google cloud functions` (python) using `gitlab.ci` yaml files.

My aim is to either update an already existing cloud function (by deleting and redeploying it) or to deploy a new function based on the name of the cloud function (and the region) as input arguments.

Below is the script I wrote :

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash

FUNCTION_NAME=$1
REGION=$2
touch functionslist.txt
gcloud beta functions list >> functionslist.txt

isInFile=$(cat functionslist.txt | grep -c FUNCTION_NAME)

if [ $isInFile -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "New Cloud Function Name, hence it shall be deployed "
else
   echo "Cloud Function Updated, hence it shall be deleted and redeployed"
   gcloud beta functions delete  ${FUNCTION_NAME} --region${REGION}
fi
```

This script is called in the following stage deploy:

```
 deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: google/cloud-sdk
  script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get --only-upgrade install kubectl google-cloud-sdk
    - gcloud config set project $GCP_PROJECT_ID
    - chmod +x delete_function.sh
    - ./delete_function.sh ${FUNCTION_NAME} ${REGION}
    - gcloud beta functions deploy ${FUNCTION_NAME} --memory ${MEMORY} --stage-bucket ${STAGE_BUCKET}  --region ${REGION}  --runtime ${RUNTIME} --trigger-http
```

The problem I am facing that each time I launch the pipeline for an updated cloud function it always considers the first case hence the "New Cloud Function Name, hence it shall be deployed" is displayed even though the cloud function already exists. I am supposed to see the following message: "Cloud Function Updated, hence it shall be deleted and redeployed".

Probably the shell script I wrote is erroneous. Any idea to solve this.

Comment: `gcloud beta functions deploy` actually replaces existing functions automatically, why delete them first?

Comment: because when I try to deploy a new cloud function having a new name and new source code I get the following error : Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions_v1beta2/worker.py", line 211, in check_or_load_user_function
    _function_handler.load_user_function()
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functionle "/user_code/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from google.cloud import pubsub
ImportError: cannot import name 'pubsub' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)